# How to become invisible to opped members in minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bukkit

I have installed a plugin called Vanish No Packet in a Minecraft Bukkit Server in which I play with my friend. I am the owner of the server but my friend is also op. I thought of trolling him by becoming invisible but he was able to see me. What can I do so that even the op players can't see me? What changes do I have to make in the permissions file? You can also download [my server's permission file](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=F3845903B90C486C!3254&authkey=!AN7Fhs8KFpY2t5o&ithint=file%2Cyml) and make changes.
Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your friend can see you because all OP players have `vanish.see` permission by default, so you need to negate it.

I recognized that you use PermissionsEX reading the link that you have provided, so you could add your friend to a group that negates this permission or you could add it specifically for him.

To only for him:

```
/pex user YourFriendNick add -vanish.see
```

To create a group:

```
/pex group aNiceGroupName add -vanish.see
/pex user YourFriendNick group add aNiceGroupName
```

With a group you can add more friends adjusting the second command, so when you are done you can delete the group and the negative permission will be remove, allowing your friends to see vanished players again with a single command:

```
/pex group aNiceGroupName delete
```

**Note:** Your friend will not be able to see any vanished players if you negate the permission.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option you can use without plugins:

```
/effect give @s minecraft:invisibility 1000000 255 true
```

It does not show particles (due to the `hideParticles` option being set to `true`), and will apply forever (a very long time!).

To reverse this effect, you can use the following command:

```
/effect clear @s minecraft:invisibility
```

Comment: @Schism, you edited my answer stating that the order of parameters is amplifier before length. However, this is simply not true in the current latest version, 1.14.4, as [shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdnL5.png).

Comment: Ah, I attempted to force [this suggested edit](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/281304) through with an update to the duration, but I copied it over wrong. (I had meant to press Improve but pressed Approve, and so I tried to copy over the edit, but I somehow missed the substantial part of it... whoops.)